# Parsing xml file over network with GData iphone

Tags: iphone, xml

I have my data on webserver in XML format. i want to use it with GData parser in my application. Please suggest how can i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ray Wenderlich has a fantastic tutorial that you could use as an example for this.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

Hopefully that gives you a better understanding of GDataXML.